# position: absolute pushes content to right in Opera/FF/IE but not with Webkit browsers

Tags: css, layout, 960.gs

I'm using 960gs to layout the page with a standard one column centred layout, header then nav then content then footer.

The #nav has vertical lists inside. If the client has javascript enabled then the lists (using JQuery) are set to pop down on hover (by changing display of the lower li's from none to block).

This means that the #nav has `position: relative` and a high z-index, with the #content set to `position: absolute` in order that the lists flow over the top of the content. Otherwise, the content moves down to accommodate the list.

It works great in Safari v5 and Chrome v11. However, FF v10 and Opera v11 (and IE but that's a given;) decide to offset the #content from the left *beginning* at the right edge of the nav, so around 800ish pixels to the right.

I've tried remedying this by setting the #container position to relative, but that does nothing. Put simply, the line `position: absolute;` is the one that changes things.

I'm at the limits of my CSS/positioning knowledge here, so any help would be much appreciated.

I've used Haml here because writing HTML is so cumbersome and verbose, but even if you don't know Haml you'll understand:

```
#container.container_16
  #header.prefix_3.grid_10
    %h1
      My wonderful web site
  #nav.prefix_3.grid_10
    %ul.vert_nav.grid_2
      %li.head
        Home
      %li.sub
        About
      %li.sub
        Contact us
  #content.prefix_3.grid_10
    %p
      Lorem ipsum...

  #footer
    %p
      You've reached the end.
```

a bit of CSS:

```
#container {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#content { 
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container_16 .grid_10 { 
  width: 580px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_3 { 
  padding-left: 180px;
}
.container_12, .container_16 { 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
}

#nav ul.vert_nav li { 
  margin-left: 0.3em;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav li.sub { 
  background-color: #000000;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

and some js:

```
(function() {

  jQuery(function($) {
    $("li.sub").toggle();
    $("#content").css("top", "12em");
    return $("ul.vert_nav").mouseenter(function() {
      return $(this).find("li.sub").show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      return $(this).find("li.sub").hide();
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

In summary:

1. To allow menus to fly over the top of the content, I need position absolute on the content div.
2. It has to work with 960gs.

To go outside of these requirements it needs to be a really solid reason.

Comment: You should be positioning your drop down elements absolutely, not the content.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts that appears to have worked, only now I can't dynamically add or remove menus without dealing with a new positioning problem, but it's much much better than the problem I had! Thank you. Would you care to add that as an answer so I can mark it correct please?

Comment: I have added that as an answer. What new positioning issues are you having?

Comment: Before, extra lists would be added to the end dynamically (for example, an admin menu if you're an admin) and they'd just stack along the end (so each column is a ul). Now that they're absolute I need to give a horizontal position ahead of time or they all sit on top of each other. It means there can be gaps depending on the menus a user has access to. I'm using SASS so perhaps there's a way to calculate the values, but still, this is a better problem than before. If I can't find a way I'll open a new question and link to it. Thanks for the example too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than positioning the `#content` absolutely you should position the drop down items absolutely instead.

For example you could have:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        No drop down
    </li>
    <li>
        A drop down
        <ul>
            <li>option 1</li>
            <li>option 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;        /* for the absolutely positioned children */
}

ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0px;
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JeAH8/**